# Maven dependency for ejb and war

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, primefaces, ejb, war

I have an ear with an ejb and a war.

```
| ear
| ---> ejb
| ---> war
| ---  ---> WEB-INF/lib
| ---  ---  ---> primefaces.jar
| ---> other dependency libs
| ---> primefaces.jar
```

I want to use primefaces push to send messages from the ejb service layer to the web clients. Therefore i need i have a dependency from the ejb and from the war to the primefaces.jar.

But i don't now how to solve this. My current problem is, that i have doubled the jar. But this leeds to a linker exception:

```
loader constraint violation: when resolving method "de.digitaljukebox.service.PushService.setEventBus(Lorg/primefaces/push/EventBus;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, TestBean, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for the method's defining class, PushService, have different Class objects for the type org/primefaces/push/EventBus used in the signature
```

I need to keep primefaces in my WEB-INF/lib, otherwise the components won't work.

I tried to set the dependency of the EJB with

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

but the ejb does not find the jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder...

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that maven dependency mess?

Setting: 
Primefaces 6.0 
Wildfly 10

Comment: Maybe it is too much work, but did you consider using only a war with EJB's inside? This is perfectly possible and works the same. You then can eliminate ear with ejb folder and other dependencies and put them all in your war...

Comment: Yeah i really consider that... I just hope for a better solution. Is it then also possible to put a persistence.xml in the war?

Comment: Yes, sure. I put everything in my war, including persistence.xml ;-) JPA, EJB, CDI, JMS, JSF, etc...  The thing is also when you keep using this setup, it will be more and more difficult to find solutions regarding classpath resolution. Also, regarding your issue: why don't you remove the primefaces jar from the WEB-INF lib? If you build the ear the right way, the war folder should be able to do classpath resolution on the 'other depencies' folder! Or, also another solution but it sounds less logical: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100966/how-to-make-an-ear-refer-war-shared-library

Comment: Primefaces.jar needs to be in Web-inf/lib... Otherwise some components aren't working correctly. I merged my ejb and my war and this seems to be a good solution for me. My project isn't going to be that huge. Thanks a lot